# Jboss Seam Booking Example Extract Shared Libs From Ear

Tags: java, jsf, jboss, seam, richfaces

Example Booking Application, which JBoss Seam is shipped with, build into EAR file of about 7 MB. That's pretty much if you consider deploying this package to a remote Jboss server and possibly redeploying it package many times during your regular work.

Lib files like richfaces and jsf-facelet make the lion's share of that EAR size. Why can't we just extract lib files into jboss-web.deployer directory on JBoss 4.2.0 GA server?

Answer (score 1):

You could move the dependent libraries out of the EAR file and place them in the proper JBoss lib directories and it should work.  But having a large EAR file is really not a signifigant issue.  Keeping all those libraries in the EAR file is preferable.  If the number of files required to deploy your work is kept to a minimum, it will make life easier for those people who have to deploy and maintain your software.